# How to select sum across 100 tables?

Tags: mysql, select

I unfortunately have spread some data across about 100 tables, and I don't have time to reorganize it, so I am curious as to how I might do a select sum(column_name) across that many tables.

I have found examples of how to sum across 2 tables, but never an example of 100.

Anybody know how?

---

Addendum: Using a very large command has resulted in a "memory exhausted" error. Is there a way to do this using LIKE ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a big query, but something like this would do it:

```
SELECT SUM(col) FROM (
  SELECT col FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col FROM table2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col FROM table3
  ...
  SELECT col FROM table100
) a
```

Comment: What if I don't have a list of every single table name? I have a pattern that I can use in a LIKE expression.

Comment: Uh oh, after building a complete command for all tables and trying it, I got a memory exhaused error.

Comment: @fubarts You can fetch table names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and then build your SQL with results from querying it. i.e. `SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE table_schema = 'myschema' AND table_name like '%xyz'`

Comment: I get the error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @fubarts - corrected that in my answer by adding an "a" at the end

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way to do this is to do lots of selects (one for each table) of the value you want to sum and just do a sum on the union of that?

Something like :

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) FROM (
            select 1 VALUE 
            UNION
            select 2 VALUE
            UNION
            select 3 VALUE) as DATA
```

Of course the selects will be selecting a column from each table and not just an integer like this, but you get the idea ...

Answer (score 0):

You seem fixated on `LIKE`, but `LIKE` is for `WHERE` clauses, not choosing tables to select from. If selecting from all the tables at once is too much for your system to handle, the obvious solution is to query each table individually and then add up the results using a perl/php/other script.

Comment: How could such a widely used language as SQL not allow something this simple and useful?

Comment: Because any normalized database would never need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select sum(sumcol) FROM (
    select sum(col) as sumcol from table1
    union all
    select sum(col) as sumcol from table2
    union all
    select sum(col) as sumcol from table3
    ...
    union all
    select sum(col) as sumcol from table100
);
```

This is done with much less memory consumption when you sum-up in union parts, too.